# XAML User Control validation

Tags: validation, xaml, user-controls

I have a user control that is a combination of a Text box and two buttons.  I have setup the Dependency property so that it binds to my model correctly.  The issue is when I have a validation error, the "red" border wraps both the text box and the buttons.

**I would like to change the behavior so that when there is an error, only the inner text box has red border but can't figure out how to do this.**

[Tried to post an image, but I am not high enough :-(  ]

My text box has this as its binding (inside the user control, this is wrapped in a grid with a stack panel for the buttons since they are dynamic)

Codebehind

```
private static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl));
```

XAML file

```
<Textbox Grid.Column="0"
         Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={StaticResource CommaFormat}
            , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor
            , AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
         x:Name="txt" 
         MaxLength="6" Height="22" Width="65" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

in my main form.. I have this xaml binding

```
<WeightTextbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,0"
               Text="{Binding SelectedDocument.Weight1,
                      Mode=TwoWay,
                      ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                      TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}" />
```

Note: this appears 5 times on a single windows form so that I can collect different weights for my document.

I have tried searching, but have not been able to find anything.

Edit (finally high enough rep to add an image)
[image]

Comment: Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Added an image of what is happening.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally had an ah-ha moment yesterday so I am posting this in case anyone comes searching.  added a Dependency Property to my WeightTextbox called "Required"

```
  private static DependencyProperty RequiredProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Required", typeof(bool), typeof(xagDateTimeCustom));

    public Boolean Required
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(RequiredProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            bool oldValue = Required;
            SetValue(RequiredProperty, value);
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e = new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(RequiredProperty, oldValue, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(e);
        }
    }
```

In my main form I do the following now.. (New Required property being set and the ValidatesOnDataErrors is set to False

```
<WeightTextbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,0"
               Required=True
               Text="{Binding SelectedDocument.Weight1,
                      Mode=TwoWay,
                      ValidatesOnDataErrors=False,
                      TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}" />
```

then inside my custom control, I implemented the IDataErrorInfo and it seems to work now.

[image]